# Get related posts of child term of custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I want to show related posts of my child taxonomy term from taxonomy terms of custom post type.

CPT: project

Taxonomy name: preferences

Parent term: 2BHK, 3 BHK

Child term of 2 BHK: completed projects, under construction

Child term of 3 BHK: same as 2 BHk with different slug

I am getting related posts of 2 BHK from parent term but not getting child terms posts i.e under construction.

**This is my effort:**

function in functions.php

```
function get_related_posts( $taxonomy = '', $args = array() )
{
    /*
     * Before we do anything and waste unnecessary time and resources, first check if we are on a single post page
     * If not, bail early and return false
     */
    if ( !is_single() )
        return false;

    /*
     * Check if we have a valid taxonomy and also if the taxonomy exists to avoid bugs further down.
     * Return false if taxonomy is invalid or does not exist
     */
    if ( !$taxonomy ) 
        return false;

    $taxonomy = filter_var( $taxonomy, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    if ( !taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) )
        return false;

    /*
     * We have made it to here, so we should start getting our stuff togther. 
     * Get the current post object to start of
     */
    $current_post = get_queried_object();

    /*
     * Get the post terms, just the ids
     */
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $current_post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids') );

    /*
     * Lets only continue if we actually have post terms and if we don't have an WP_Error object. If not, return false
     */
    if ( !$terms || is_wp_error( $terms ) )
        return false;

    /*
     * Set the default query arguments
     */
    $defaults = array(
        'post_type' => $current_post->post_type,
        'post__not_in' => array( $current_post->ID),
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'terms' => $terms,
                'include_children' => false,
            ),
        ),
    );

    /*
     * Validate and merge the defaults with the user passed arguments
     */
    if ( is_array( $args ) ) {
        $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    } else {
        $args = $defaults;
    }

    /*
     * Now we can query our related posts and return them
     */
    $q = get_posts( $args );

    return $q;
}
```

single-custom_post_type.php

```
<div class="row">
            <?php
                if ( function_exists( 'get_related_posts' ) ) {
                    $related_posts = get_related_posts( 'preferences', array( 'posts_per_page' => -1) );
                    if ( $related_posts ) {
                        foreach ( $related_posts as $post ) {
                            setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                <h4> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?> </a> </h4>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        }
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                    }
                }
            ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: @SallyCJ i want to show post of "under construction" under 2 BHK or 3 BHK from which the current post is.

Comment: Well, if the current post is in "2 BHK" and `include_children` is set to `true`, then you should also see posts in the child "Under Construction" category under the "2 BHK" category. Unless for non-public posts (private, unpublished, etc.) which are not included by default.

Comment: i am getting related post of 2 BHK not of 2 BHK -> under construction.

Comment: So you don't want to include the posts in the parent category (2 BHK)? I.e. Only those directly assigned to 2 BHK -> under construction?

Comment: yes, exactly if the posts is assigned to 2 BHK-> under construction then related posts are of 2 BHK -> under construction. same way for 2 BHK-> completed projects.

Comment: sure we can delete.

Comment: Not sure if you've found a solution, but there's no built-in function in WordPress for what you're trying to do (except for posts having *one* category). However, you could use ACF and add a custom field to your "project" posts, e.g. name it "Related-by categories" and choose the categories that you want to be used when querying the related posts.

Comment: And another option is, something like `if ( has_term( 'under construction', 'preferences' ) ) { show only related posts in "under construction" category } else { show related posts from all parent and child terms }` - but it requires that you to manually specify the category..